# Get access token during Auth Registration Handler(Auth. Provider)

Tags: auth

We are using Auth. Provider for single-sign on with our product platform.
But we need to do a separate call to get other information in Auth.RegistrationHandler but we need get access token that is issued during authorization(SF internally uses that access token to get user info from user info end point and pass the user info information as userdata but not access token). We are not able to get the access token in Auth.RegistrationHandler.

As far as I know we can get access token by using Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken, but this user context and Auth.RegistrationHandler runs is specific user and even before creating the user we want to get the access in registration handler.

```
 global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    /*String accesstoken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SXXXXXXXXXXXyw', 'Open ID connect');
    System.debug('@@@accesstoken'+accesstoken);*/
```

[image]

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: You have to call `AuthToken.getAccessToken` outside of the handler. There are some Q&As on this topic here, take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

In the registration handler what you could potentially get access to is the ID token, not the access token. You could potentially write some Apex code but it would have to be in the context of the user and the user should be created

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to run the getAuthToken code in the user's context